# iOS: Create a custom graph with content that changes at runtime

Tags: ios, user-interface, graphics, graph, core-animation

I'd like to create a graph with a lot of custom content and **add information to this as the time elapses** while the app runs.

The graph I have in mind will look similar to this:

[image]

The pink horizontal bar gets drawn as the time elapses.. as with the black value curve. The yellow vertical bar is linked to a specific event and I'd like to be able to draw more than one. Once the pink bar reaches the letter **t** then the first part of the graph will be overridden (<---- this is the direction of the overriding animation).

Any suggestion on how I can get this started? Any decent tutorial?

I'd like to do this in a custom UIView.

**Any idea on which framework I should use in iOS?** Is there a good tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1):

I can advice to use [CorePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Example-Graphs) library.
It's flexible well-documented library that supports different kind of graphs.